# ZXing qr code scanner on windows platform

Tags: c#, maui, zxing.net, maui-windows

How can we implement the qr code scanner on windows platform in .net maui.

I've implemented it and it is working well on Ios and Android but on windows platform when we press the scan button it says it is not supported. Any solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `Windows is not supported at this time for barcode scanning.` You can check this link https://github.com/redth/ZXing.Net.Maui for more information.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT so how we can implement it on windows any other solution?

Comment: ZXing project belongs to the third party, and MAUI does not have the elements to achieve the qr code scanner on the windows platform. You can make the requests on the GitHub to make a contact with the ZXing project team. Otherwise, you can turn to other Nuget package.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT sure do you have any idea of other open source NuGet packages through which we can implement the QR code reader on windows

Comment: You can check this video about [how to use the Camera.MAUI scan the QR code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuvFrIS9wm0).